# boost python :LNK1104 unable to open“libboost_python39-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_82.lib”

Tags: python, c++, boost

I used boost:: python to wrap some C++ function, error occurs :LNK1104  unable to open “libboost_python39-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_82.lib”

[image]

However, It succeeds when I compile some other simple examples under the same configuration. The following is the code that compiles successfully

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "SomeClass.h"
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(member)
{
    class_<SomeClass>("SomeClass", init<std::string>())
        .def_readwrite("name", &SomeClass::name)
        .def("getNumber", &SomeClass::getNumber)
        .def("setNumber", &SomeClass::setNumber)
        ;

}
```

What is the possible reason that it didn't work in my code above but works in another piece of code with the same configuration？

Environment: visual studio 2019